# Why do I get a Timer error after launch app

Tags: fluid-framework

I'm trying to test Fluid Framework in a React app and in an Angular app.
In both, I have the same error few seconds after app launch :

```
private handler() {
> 151 |     assert(this.runningState, "Running timer missing handler");
      | ^  152 |     const restart = this.runningState.restart;
  153 |     if (restart !== undefined) {
  154 |         // Restart with remaining time
```

Seems to be a connexion error with tinylidious server (socket) but I don't understand where is my mistake.
Using 0.27 version.

Thank's for any ideas ;-)

Comment: Hey, did you base this code off a specific example? I'm trying to repro.

Comment: Without a further investigation, my guess is that we're calling a process out of order in the summarizer.

Comment: I confirm it's a pb within the ctor of the SummaryManager but don't understand why

Comment: delete nodemodules, update to react 17 and it works ;-) Now looking at angular app to correct it

Comment: Update zone.js and @angular-devkit/build-angular and works fine now. GREAT. Time to have fun ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may be caused by out of date dependencies. You can try deleting node_modules and reinstalling or upgrading major dependencies.

To talk to the **need** for a timer is also interesting. Fluid uses [summaries](https://fluidframework.com/docs/advanced/summarizer/) to quickly get new clients up to speed on the content of a document. In a simplified implementation of Fluid, the state of a Fluid application is just the log of all operations in that document. For performance reasons, we summarize that state periodically so that new users don't need to run through **every** operation (for a long running application this could be hundreds of thousands of ops).

These Summaries are created based on heuristics, either by number of ops or by the timer that you're finding an issue with. Just so long as the app is summarized in some reasonable timeline, the app performance is improved.